# Resources (js or css) not found into jsp page with spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, resources

I'm trying to include some resources into my jsp pages like this one:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery/jquery.js" var="jqueryUrl" />
<script src="${jqueryUrl}"><jsp:text/></script>
```

But I obtain always `NOT FOUND 404`, why?

This is my project structure:
[image]

I'm using Spring Framework version 4.2.4.RELEASE if it can help you..

Into Security Configuration I have this:

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/resources/**").permitAll()
```

and into Servlet configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ServletContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceHandlerRegistry) {
            resourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/");
        }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in this way, i change this one

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/resources/**").permitAll()
```

to

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/resources/*").permitAll()
```